# How to scan single line params string and return two arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, json, wufoo

I have following single line string:

```
params = {"FieldStructure"=>"{\"Fields\":[{\"Title\":\"Company Name\",\"Type\":\"text\",\"ID\":\"Field6\"},{\"Title\":\"Email\",\"Type\":\"email\",\"ID\":\"Field5\"}]}", "Field6"=>"tettetette", "Field5"=>"test@tessss.pl", "EntryId"=>"25"}
```

Formated version:

```
params = {
  "FieldStructure"=>"
    {\"Fields\":[
      {\"Title\":\"Company Name\",\"Type\":\"text\",\"ID\":\"Field6\"},
      {\"Title\":\"Email\",\"Type\":\"email\",\"ID\":\"Field5\"}]}",
    "Field6"=>"tettetette", 
    "Field5"=>"test@tessss.pl", 
    "EntryId"=>"25"
}
```

I would like to receive: `[["Company Name", "Field6"], ["Email", "Field5"]]`

I tried to use scan method but have some problems:

```
>>  fields = params['FieldStructure'].scan(/Title\":\"(.+?)\".+ID\":\"(.+?)\"/)  
=> [["Company Name", "Field5"]]
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Is there any reason to not treat it as JSON payload? FieldStructure is a well formed json string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-regex solution:

```
require 'json'
params = {"FieldStructure"=>"{\"Fields\":[{\"Title\":\"Company Name\",\"Type\":\"text\",\"ID\":\"Field6\"},{\"Title\":\"Email\",\"Type\":\"email\",\"ID\":\"Field5\"}]}", "Field6"=>"tettetette", "Field5"=>"test@tessss.pl", "EntryId"=>"25"}

a = JSON.parse(params["FieldStructure"])
out = a["Fields"].map {|a| [a["Title"],a["ID"]]}
p out  # [["Company Name", "Field6"], ["Email", "Field5"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is:

```
params['FieldStructure'].scan(/Title\":\"(.+?)\".+?ID\":\"(.+?)\"/)
```

Your .+ before ID was greddy, meaning that it would consume the most characters it can until find the next ID. the ? in the end turns it in no greddy.