# How will be the best way to render array of arrays in erb template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, sinatra, erb

I have an array `[["Company Name", "Field6"], ["Email", "Field5"]]`

And from that array I am creating array of fields with values:

```
[
  [{:label=>"Company Name", :value=>"gfdgfd"}],
  [{:label=>"Email", :value=>"gfdgfd@gfd.pl"}]
]
```

using

```
fields = [["Company Name", "Field6"], ["Email", "Field5"]]
# first element in array is Label and second is param id
fields_with_values = fields.collect do |field| 
 [
   label: field[0],
   value: params[field[1]]
 ]
end
```

and then I want to pass that labels and values to erb template(something like):

```
# template.erb
<% fields_with_values.each do |field| %>
  l: <%= field.label %>
  v: <%= field.value %>
<% end %>
```

How will be the best way to collect these fields_with_values ? Maybe I should use Object.new

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to in clear, simple way render this ``template.erb``

Comment: and what's wrong with that you are doing?

Comment: There is no ``field.label`` and ``field.value``, so I collect  ``fields_with_values`` in wrong way

Comment: You want it as objects or does hash works?

Comment: I would like to create an object. But I am also wondering if this will be the best way to collect that?

Comment: I'd personally avoid instantiating new Objects for this case, unless there is some business logic involved with the data which hasn't been mentioned here.

Comment: +1 Wizard. Classifying and instantiating each element is an unnecessary step whose only purpose is to facilitate the use of dot notation in the view.

Comment: I'd wonder why the whole (outer) array isn't in an object, with each of those inner objects being available via attributes. Using nested primitive data types instead of objects is a code smell.

Comment: @iain What? Arrays *are* objects. I agree that elements should be accessible by attribute (keyed), therefore a hash is recommended.

Comment: @gg_s *Please* don't be pedantic when it's obvious what I'm saying, pedantry doesn't add anything to any debate anywhere. Quite clearly an `Address` or `Customer` (or something like it) object would be better here than a nested Array.

Comment: @iain This particular nested array was converted from [a params hash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15948128/1153362). Extra steps would be needed to parse and normalize the data, for negligible benefit. I don't see a net gain here. Nested arrays are perfectly fine in this guy's case.

Comment: @gg_s There's always perl for people who like nested hashes and arrays ;) but if you're using Ruby (or any other language that objects are first class citizens) and using a nested primitive type that's a [code smell](http://solnic.eu/2012/06/25/get-rid-of-that-code-smell-primitive-obsession.html). I also doubt that it's only function will be to be rendered. How often does that happen? No translation? No storage? No side effects?

Comment: @iain I agree; I would have used a custom response object myself. But this discussion of *why* it's a nested array is off-topic. Here we have a nested array, *for whatever reason*, and it needs to be rendered. At face value, no abstraction is necessary. Probably not the best solution in all cases, but it answers the question as written.

Comment: @gg_s that's why I've made a comment under the question, and I'd give votes to an answer that answered the questioner's _problem_, which isn't always the same as answering the question as is. If OP's were always the best judge of what they need to ask and why then most of them probably wouldn't need to ask the question anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fields = [["Company Name", "Field6"], ["Email", "Field5"]]
# first element in array is Label and second is param id

fields_with_values = fields.collect do |label, param_id| 
  # It looks like there is no need for a nested array here, so just return a Hash
  {
    label: label,
    value: params[param_id]
  }
end

#=> [{:label=>"Company Name", :value=>"gfdgfd"}, {:label=>"Email", :value=>"gfdgfd@gfd.pl"}]
```

It looks like you are trying to use dot syntax to get values out of a Ruby Hash similar to how you would use dot syntax for a JavaScript object (e.g. `field.label`). Unfortunately this doesn't work for Ruby. I wish it did because it looks very clean. For the Ruby Hash you must use an index, which is a symbol in this case: `field[:label]`. Your ERB code will look something like this:

```
# template.erb
<% fields_with_values.each do |field| %>
  l: <%= field[:label] %>
  v: <%= field[:value] %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 5):

Convert to a hash instead.

```
fields = [["Company Name", "Field6"], ["Email", "Field5"]]

fields_with_values = Hash[*fields.flatten]
# => {"Company Name"=>"Field6", "Email"=>"Field5"}
```

In your view, parse the hash:

```
<% fields_with_values.each do |label, value| %>
  l: <%= label %>
  v: <%= params[value.intern] %>
<% end %>
```

Note that this will break if your input array is uneven, ie. a key without a value.

---

#### EDIT

As mentioned in a comment below (+1), duplicate keys will not work. Fields that have the same label as another field are no good.

Comment: I like this! You just need to mention that it won't work with duplicate labels (Hash keys). That doesn't seem likely to be a problem in this case.

Comment: One thing: value is not ``Field5`` but ``params['Field5']``

Comment: Updated. I interned `value` which produces a symbol (`params[:Field5]`). If you want a string instead, remove `.intern`.

Answer (score 1):

The easy most basic way would be:

```
class Foo
 attr_accessors :label, :value
 def initialize (label, value)
   @label = label
   @value = value
 end
end

fields_with_values = fields.map do |field|
   Foo.new(field[0], params[field[1]])
end
```

from here on you can make it more Ruby way with splat operator or create the objects on the fly, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

l: 
  v:

I would do

```
fields_with_values = fields.collect do |field|
  {label: field[0], value: params[field[1]}
end
```

And in the view

```
<% fields_with_values.each do |field| %>
  l: <%= field[:label] %>
  v: <%= field[:value] %>
<% end %>
```

However, lets say label is a company and value is an e-mail. If you have a class like

```
class Company < SomethingOrNothing
  attr_accessible :name, email

  # methods here
end
```

You could do

```
@companies = fields.collect do |field|
  Company.new(name: field[0], email: field[1]) 
end
```

And then

```
<% @companies.each do |company| %>
  l: <%= comapny.name %>
  v: <%= company.email %>
<% end %>
```

However, most likely creating a new class just for that is over engineering, unless you will use this class over and over in your code.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I will use it only in this one template. And what about using ``Struct`` for that?

Comment: Well, not sure about structs. Never used it myself - I usually go with hash or create a class for it. Not sure what exactly is the advantages to use a Struct.